# Check if a string is a base 16 number

Tags: c++, string, radix

I've been trying to solve this task, but I had no positive results.

So, my task is to check if a string is a base 16 number.

example  : s="1AB",  it will show YES 427

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
 int power (int a, int b)
 {
     if(b==1) return a; 
     else return a*power(a,b-1);
 }
 void conv(char s[],int &n)
 {
     int S=0,i,p=0;
     for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
         if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')
            S+=(s[i]-48) * power(16,p); //ex:s[i]='1' ==> S+=(49-49)*...
         else S+=(s[i]-55) * power(16,p); //s[i]='A' ==> S+=(65-55) *...
         p++;
     }
 }
int main()
{
 int n,i,k=0;
 char s[255];
 cin.get(s,255);
 cin.get();
 n=strlen(s);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     if(strchr("0123456789ABCDEF",s[i])) k++;
 }
 if(k==0) cout<<"not in base 16";
 else{
    conv(s,n); cout<<s;}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just thought "Oh nice SO has added C++ runnable code snippets!"...

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Annabelle the problem is "It doesn't work" ;)

Comment: I think you want to check whether the number is correct hex number and also convert that number to decimal. Is that correct? 
444 is not decimal value of 1AB? What is 444?

Comment: @Annabelle I think my "conv" function has some issues, but I can't find out what's wrong.

Comment: @abdullah my bad, it is 427; 427=1*16^2+10*16^1+11*16^0

Answer (score 1):

If you want almost clean solution, you can check mine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool IsHex(string& in) {
    for (char d : in) {
        if (!isxdigit(d)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int Convert(string& in) {
    int val = 0;
    for (char d : in) {
        val = val * 16 + (isdigit(d)? d - '0' : 10 + (isupper(d)? d - 'A' : d - 'a'));
    }
    return val;
}

int main() {
    string in;
    cin >> in;
    if (!IsHex(in)) cout << "Not a correct hex number" << endl;
    else cout << "YES " << Convert(in) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I have made some changes in your code to make it work. You can easily find out changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
 int power (int a, int b)
 {
     if (b == 0) return 1;
     if(b==1) return a; 
     else return a*power(a,b-1);
 }
 int conv(char s[],int &n)
 {
     int S=0,i,p=0;
     for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
         if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')
            S+=(s[i]-48) * power(16,p); //ex:s[i]='1' ==> S+=(49-49)*...
         else S+=(s[i]-55) * power(16,p); //s[i]='A' ==> S+=(65-55) *...
         p++;
     }
     return S;
 }
int main()
{
 int n,i,k=0;
 char s[255];
 cin.get(s,255);
 cin.get();
 n=strlen(s);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     if(!strchr("0123456789ABCDEF",s[i])) break;
 }
 if(i < n) cout<<"not in base 16";
 else{
    cout << conv(s,n) << endl;}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `std::isxdigit`, for example:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool IsThisStringAHexNumber(std::string const &str)
{
    for (size_t i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; ++i)
        if (!std::isxdigit(str[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsThisStringAHexNumber("298722h2jjh") << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsThisStringAHexNumber("2abc66f") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
false
true
```